# How to sort by specific 'field' in filename

Tags: bash, sorting, ls

I have files in a folder where the filenames are of the form:

`2352_GF_somerandomstring.txt`, i.e. someNumber_twoletters_somestring.

using flags on `ls` the best I can achieve is to sort by different criteria similarly for `sort`.

What I'd like is to have the list sorted by the 'twoletters'. I.e. ignore the prefix-number and sort by the 'GF'-portion (in the sample), but still show me the complete file names (i.e. including the prefix-number).

The closest I got is (without writing a complete script):
`ls | cut -d '_' -f2- |sort`

but the cut part removes everything in front, which I still need to see.

Any ideas on how to do this in a simple way? (Hopefully a oneliner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:
`ls | sort -t '_' -k 2`

-t is separator and -k is column

Comment: perfect. exactly what I was looking for. thank you